# Does being targeted with Moonlight Hunt allow my creature to return damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Opponent targeted me with [Moonlight Hunt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoonlight%20Hunt%5d); would my creature [It That Rides as One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIt%20That%20Rides%20as%20One%5d) return damage or do any fighting to any of the wolves or werewolves that were chosen to fight me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? What "fighting" are you referring to?

Comment: Choose target creature you don't control. Each creature you control that's a Wolf or a Werewolf deals damage equal to its power to that creature.

Comment: Right. That's the text of Moonlight Hunt. It says that some creatures deal damage to a specific other creature, and that's it. It doesn't say anything about something "returning" or anything "fighting", so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Pretty sure it's just some inexact language - the OP is saying "return" as in "deal damage in return", and they're saying "fight" to mean "deal damage to". Obviously that's not what the card says or what fight means, but... it's what the OPs asking about.

Comment: Right; that's how I figured after a few readings. dokepa, note that "fight" is a specific keyword in Magic; this card doesn't use that word so it doesn't cause creatures to fight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

The only thing that [Moonlight Hunt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoonlight%20Hunt%5d) does is specifically what it says: each wolf or werewolf that your opponent controls will deal damage to your [It That Rides as One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIt%20That%20Rides%20as%20One%5d). Your creature will not deal damage in return because the spell doesn't say it does.

Note that Moonlight Hunt does not cause creatures to fight each other. "Fight" is a keyword that causes creatures to deal damage to each other; which may be what you are thinking of. But Moonlight Hunt doesn't use the word "fight"; so it doesn't have anything to do with "fighting".